# Reversing a string in python

Tags: python

I want to find a palindrome in a string.

```
mystring = "1234321"
```

Why does

```
mystring[3:7:-1]
```

not work, but

```
second = mystring[3:7]
reversed = second[::-1]
```

this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have to tell python to "start" with the end index and "end" with the start index:

```
>>> "0123456789"[7:3:-1]
'7654'
```

Comment: In the case of the OP's example, mystring[6:2:-1]

Answer (score 0):

When you reversing the string on the fly like that, you need to put the larger index first.  You should use:

```
mystring[7:3:-1]
```

instead of:

```
mystring[3:7:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

mystring[::-1] implies the start and the end.

Using [3:7:-1] you give an "increment", start index and finish index, but you are also
instantly out of your string boundaries....